# How to dynamically assign array with known values

Tags: c++

I just found this "gem" in some code that was randomly crashing. It is supposed to assign an array of floats to `bins` and the number of bins to `nBins`. Depending on some conditions there are different arrays with different sizes. Of course this fails (or is undefined behavior) because `tmpBins` goes out of scope, and the compiler can reuse its memory.

```
float* bins = 0;
int nBins = 5;

if (condition1) {
  float tmpBins[] = {0.,20.,30.,40.,800.};
  bins = tmpBins;
  nBins = 5;
} else {
  // more cases 
}
```

I wonder how I should fix this. I could allocate memory with `new` and copy it over with `memcpy` or a loop. I could use a vector, but I don't have C++11's vector initializers, so I'd probably have to add the elements manually with `push_back`, which I'd like to avoid. I'd rather not change too much of the surrounding legacy code, so if I change the type of `bins` it should still be usable as an drop-in replacement for an array. What's the best/most ideomatic way of fixing this in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), you don't need the C++11 initializer lists to make it work, just [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) them:

```
std::vector<float> bins;

...

static const float tmpBins[] = {0.,20.,30.,40.,800.};
nBins = sizeof(tmpBins) / sizeof(tmpBins[0]);
bins.insert(bins.end(), tmpBins, tmpBins + nBins);
```

Or if you want to replace the current entries:

```
bins = std::vector<float>(tmpBins, tmpBins + nBins);
```

Comment: Note that you may use `assign` instead of `insert` (and removing extra argument `bins.end()`).